# What happened to FN-1824?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In the movie, the last we see of FN-1824 (the Stormtrooper guarding the interrogation room) is him dropping his blaster as he walks away.  Does anyone know what happened to him after that scene?  He would be walking through the corridors without his weapon, which I'm sure would get him in a lot of trouble, not to mention the fact that it would be very easy to figure out that it was he who let Rey escape*—never mind that he was the victim of a Jedi Mind Trick.  Considering Kylo Ren's fit of destructive rage upon discovering that Rey is gone, I can expect that he would be in some serious hot water—that is, *if* he survived.

*Remember how easy it was for them earlier in the movie to search the records to attempt to determine who helped Poe Dameron escape (before Kylo Ren immediately declared who it was)?

Comment: Shouldn't he introduce himself as 1824, FN-1824?

Comment: @Whovian4Life    Ha, ha  :)   But seriously, I don't think Rey cared about his identity at that point—it was more like "Hey, you!  Get me out of here!"

Comment: IIRC they didn't search the records to determine that it was FN-2187 who helped Poe escape, but Kylo who remembered that FN-2187 behaved weirdly in the battle of Jakku and was therefore most likely to be the one who helped Poe.

Comment: @Kevin, someone told Kylo Ren that they were reviewing roll calls or some sort of records to figure out who it was.  That was when he immediately mentioned FN-2187, catching everyone by surprise.  Thanks, though, for noticing my mistake there.

Comment: [Rey asked him to escort her to a ship she could escape in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbpgM-JTang&feature=youtu.be&t=1m19s). Well, I think that's How it Should Have Ended!

Comment: Wasn't he supposed to be JB-007 since he was played by Daniel Craig? Where did you get the name FN-1824?

Comment: @alpha1  See the [Wookiepedia article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/FN-1824) on FN-1824.  Basically, the JB-007 designation was never more than an informal one created by fans (kind of like TR-8R), so there was a gap in the canon.  A LEGO Star Wars video game (not canon) introduced the designation FN-1824, and [Pablo Hidalgo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pablo_Hidalgo) has confirmed that even though the game is non-canon, its names for previously unidentified characters can be considered canon.  Hence, the stormtrooper's canon designation is FN-1824.

Comment: @bob thanks for the very clear explanation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The novelisation indicates that Rey told him (via her Force powers) to go back to his room and to not tell anyone what had happened.

> *“I will remove these restraints. And leave this cell, with the door
> open, **and retire to my living quarters.** I will speak of this encounter
> to no one.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Force Awakens: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

and

> *There was no hesitation. “I will drop my weapon,” he said. He set it
> on the floor, opened the cell door, and **headed out, presumably to his
> living quarters.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Force Awakens: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

We learn later that he made it back to his quarters. After Rey's escape, he's debriefed but there appear to be no further ramifications. Ren seems to accept that he was tricked by a Force user rather than incompetent in his duties.

> *“Yes.” Ren’s voice was almost indifferent, as if the bulk of his
> thoughts were elsewhere. He looked at the officer. “The trooper who
> was on guard?” “Still being debriefed, sir. He doesn’t remember what
> happened. One minute he was at his post, at ease. The next, he found
> himself in his quarters, changing out of uniform. Initial assessment
> indicates he is telling the truth.” The officer hesitated. **“If you
> would wish to try stronger methods I can…”***
>
> *“No—no. **Keep questioning him. Just—questioning.** He may remember
> something.” His tone darkened. “The girl. She’s here somewhere.
> There’s nowhere for her to go. When you find her, bring her…” His
> voice drifted away, as did his attention.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Force Awakens: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks for finding that material, but what about the blaster?  Wouldn't he have been noticed without it walking back to his room?  Or could it just have been that people noticed but didn't say anything?

Comment: @Bob Given that FN-2187 was told to "Submit your blaster for inspection", it might not be entirely out-of-place to see troopers without a blaster.

Comment: @Bob - I should imagine that it's very unusual to see a trooper without a blaster. Presumably he just didn't bump into anyone who notices/cares on his way back to his living space.

Comment: Ren’s acceptance of this failure without further (fatal) consequences for the stormtrooper may also be related to my contention that [the First Order is much weaker than the Empire was](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116380/7700). They cannot afford to waste perfectly-good stormtroopers the way the Empire could.

Comment: @KRyan - After his world class tantrum earlier, I just think that he's less interested in beating the crap out of a blame-free trooper.

Comment: His room was probably pretty close by. Would you assign storm troopers to posts far away from their living quarters? Would you have only one dormitory in a base that huge? I'd say he probably just didn't run into anyone on his way back.

Comment: @Valorum Well, we've seen Ren mostly avoid the usual "blame the first guy that comes around for everything" that was so common in Legend Siths (and to a certain extent, the "bad guys" in Canon). He seems pretty sane as these guys go - where someone like Palpatine would tear the poor guy apart, Ren sees he was utterly dominated by someone far above his power scale - nothing to blame him for.

Comment: @Luaan - I'm struggling to recall when Palpatine had cause to blame anyone for anything. He seems pretty in control, until it's time to fight someone.

Comment: @Valorum Well, yeah, he was quite a master of himself in the prequels. In the originals, there were a few hints that he's quite scary - e.g. the "redoubling of efforts" when word of Palpatine coming to oversee the construction of the DSII is spread (though that is likely an entirely deliberate image). Vader seems to act by far more impulsive (some Legends authors make him quite impulsive, some more like a strict and fair commander...). I guess I'm mostly imagining the old-school Siths from the early days of the Old Republic. Or maybe I'm too biased by the Jedi propaganda... :)

Comment: @Luuan also to note it was by the same one who utterly dominated ren hmself.....so he is probably a bit humbled there at that moment