# Do all stormtroopers carry blasters?

Tags: star-wars, stormtroopers

While looking at [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/144793/15899), I was wondering just how out-of-place a blasterless trooper would be.  All of my searches were unhelpful, though.

So, let's say I'm a storm trooper posted on a major installation, such as the Death Star or Starkiller Base.  Am I guaranteed to have been assigned a blaster?  How unlikely is it for me to see another trooper walking somewhere without a blaster?

Comment: I'm struggling to recall any time in the original trilogy when you see an off-duty trooper

Answer (score 8):

> Am I guaranteed to have been assigned a blaster?

## Yes

It was standard equipment according to [**Wookieepedia**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/E-11_blaster_rifle)

> The E-11 blaster rifle was a light but powerful blaster rifle manufactured by BlasTech Industries. It served as the **standard issue weapon** of Imperial stormtroopers, and was based on the DC-15A blaster used by clone troopers during the Clone Wars.

That's not to say you might not get a different weapon depending on your role in the [**Stormtrooper Corps**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Stormtrooper_Corps)

Generally, it would have been held in a holster..when not actually being brandished / carried though.

[image]

Given that the Stormtrooper helmet had well-known vision limitations one could excuse a fellow trooper for not noticing an *empty* holster though!

Comment: I don't disagree with your idea; however, I find the use of the phrase **standard issue** as proof flawed. I think a better explanation is that Stormtroopers are primarily soldiers and would not be given mundane tasks like maintenance (Not sure about TFA). Their main task on a ship is more akin to that of Traditional Marines, security and defense of the vessel. On that, if you are expected to wear the cumbersome armor, I believe it would be expected that you were to carry your weapon; mainly, because the armor implies you are on duty, your duty is to defend the vessel with your weapon.Not Fact

Comment: Unlike those boot camp movies like Full Metal Jacket - whenever we were on base, we would have to withdraw/return personal weapons and rifles from/into the armoury whenever going on/off duty. We would be in full uniform walking from our barrack to the armoury - so you regularly see soldiers on base in uniform without weapons. I don't know directly about naval ships - but I imagine from conversations with sailors that weapons are handled the same way on board. The question is - do Stormtroopers sleep with their weapons?

Comment: My point is - an unarmed Stormtrooper who is wearing armour could just be going from the armoury to their quarters.

Comment: BlasTech.......that sounds very “ACME” cheap to me. No wonder stormtroopers are terrible shots. It wasn’t the troopers at all. It was their cheap blasters that couldn’t shoot straight worth a darn.